# Freeswitch ACL configuration for remote event socket

Tags: node.js, virtual-machine, virtualbox, acl, freeswitch

I have a FS server running on one server and on a remote server I have a Node JS instance controlling it using node_esl (a Node JS Event Socket library for FS).

Every time I'm sending a request to the server I have the following error:

```
[WARNING] mod_event_socket.c:2603 IP ::ffff:192.168.59.3 Rejected by acl "loopback.auto"
```

FS server has 2 interfaces: one is using a public IP and the second one is on a private network (192.168.59.0/24).

I checked the acl.conf.xml file and event_socket.con.xml and I do not see anything special so far.

One last thing: this is a dev environment and FS is running in a VM (VirtualBox). The interface used for the VM is 192.168.59.103 and the GW is 192.168.59.3
So this might be a NAT issue if not an ACL issue (or both).

Do you have any idea of what the ACL configuration should be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out why:
ACL was not really that well configured. The one used was not opening the right connection for event_socket. So either Event_Socket was opened for local use only or for external use only.
Had to recreate a new ACL with local access opened (necessary if you want to use fs_cli) and adding the IPs of the controlling servers.

Thx for your suggestion regarding IPv6, I tested it earlier and found out it has no effect on my "issue"

Comment: Do you have a copy to hand of what you had to do. I am in the same position.

Comment: @TheHumbleRat  No. I moved to an other project and do not have access to this one anymore. But it was an IPv6 configuration issue

Answer (score 10):

You must go to FreeSWITCH/conf/autoload_configs/event_socket.conf.xml and uncoment and edit acl line:
`<param name="apply-inbound-acl" value="loopback.auto"/>`
you must write something like *my_acl* instead of *loopback.auto*

After that you must go to FreeSWITCH/conf/autoload_configs/acl.conf.xml and there write something like this:

```
<list name="my_acl" default="deny">
 <node type="allow" cidr="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/32"/>
 <node type="allow" cidr="xxx.xxx.xxx.0/24"/>
</list>
```

After this go to fs_cli and tape command:

`reloadacl`

Enjoy!

**EDIT:**

Make sure following:

```
<list name="my_acl" default="deny">
 <node type="allow" cidr="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/32"/>
 <node type="allow" cidr="xxx.xxx.xxx.0/24"/>
</list>
```

becomes:

```
<list name="my_acl" default="deny">
 <node type="allow" cidr="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/32"/>
 <node type="allow" cidr="xxx.xxx.xxx.0/24"/>


  <node type="allow" cidr="192.168.42.42/32"/>
  <node type="allow" domain="$${domain}"/>
  <!-- this allow fs_cli to connect else fs_cli wont work --!>
  <node type="allow" cidr="127.0.0.1/32" />
</list>
```

Comment: Segmentation fault when i do `reload mod_acl`

Comment: It seems to me that you should also run `reload mod_event_socket`

Answer (score 2):

There's some info on how to get it to work here:
https://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Mod_event_socket#Configuration

After a bit of trial and error, all I had to do to get rid of the error was the following:

1. Open FreeSWITCH/conf/autoload_configs/event_socket.conf.xml
2. Uncomment the following line:

```html
<param name="apply-inbound-acl" value="loopback.auto"/>
```

Here's my working event_socket.conf.xml file:

```html
<configuration name="event_socket.conf" description="Socket Client">
  <settings>
    <param name="nat-map" value="false"/>
    <param name="listen-ip" value="::"/>
    <param name="listen-port" value="8021"/>
    <param name="password" value="ClueCon"/>
    <param name="apply-inbound-acl" value="loopback.auto"/>
    <!--<param name="stop-on-bind-error" value="true"/>-->
  </settings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

I manually created `loopback.auto` list under `acl.conf.xml`

```
<list name="loopback.auto" default="allow">
    <node type="allow" cidr="172.31.0.0/16"/>
    <node type="allow" cidr="52.67.85.153/32"/> 
</list>
```

Where `172.31.0.0/16` is Freeswitch local IP address.

In event_socket.conf.xml file I leave loopback.auto:

```
<param name="apply-inbound-acl" value="loopback.auto"/>
```

Then run `reloadacl` and `reloadxml`. In my case I needed to restart Freeswitch to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

It could happen because of IPv6 issue:
https://freeswitch.org/jira/browse/FS-7638

As a workaround, you can try to change event_socket bind address from :: to 192.168.59.x in autoload_configs/event_socket.conf.xml

Comment: No, I tested this, but this was not the root cause of this issue. I found it in the ACL configuration as explained in my comment.